# Django admin page doesn't show tables of database (djangobook chapter 06)

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, django-admin

I am doing the [`Activating the Admin Interface`](http://django-book.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chapter06.html#activating-the-admin-interface) part in djangobook chapter 06. At the end of that part one has to run the development server and go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`.

However I see this:
[image: My Django admin page]

Instead of something like this(from the djangobook):
[image: How it should look like]

This is strange because I have data stored in a table of my mysql database that is linked to my django project in the `settings.py` file.

This is the `DATABASES` dictionary in my `settings.py` file of my django project:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',                   
        'USER': 'root',                      
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',                 
        'HOST': 'localhost',                    
        'PORT': '',                      
    }
}
```

The mysql prompt shows this:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| mydb               |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use mydb;
mysql> show tables;
+----------------------------+
| Tables_in_mydb             |
+----------------------------+
| auth_group                 |
| auth_group_permissions     |
| auth_message               |
| auth_permission            |
| auth_user                  |
| auth_user_groups           |
| auth_user_user_permissions |
| books_author               |
| books_book                 |
| books_book_authors         |
| books_publisher            |
| django_admin_log           |
| django_content_type        |
| django_session             |
+----------------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why am I not seeing the contents of `mydb` in my admin page?

Might be relevant:

```
mysql> select User from mysql.user;
+------------------+
| User             |
+------------------+
| root             |
| debian-sys-maint |
| root             |
| root             |
+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to keep reading http://django-book.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chapter06.html#adding-your-models-to-the-admin-site

> There’s one crucial part we haven’t done yet...
>   Within the books directory (mysite/books), create a file called
>   admin.py, and type in the following lines of code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.books.models import Publisher, Author, Book

admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your model in the admin.py file which is inside your app directory.

If there is not admin.py you have to create one and then register it.

In my case I have a Registeration model I have created admin.py file inside the app directory and I added the following code.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Registeration

admin.site.register(Registeration)
```